# React String concatenation behaviour - is this normal?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've got a small React component that looks like this:

```
export default function HelloStarWars(props) {
    const data = useFetch(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${props.id}`);
    const { name } = data;

    return (
        <h1>Hello {name || "..."}!</h1>
    );
}
```

I've been trying to play around with Cypruss.io and I noticed something quite odd when I could get a `.contains()` working correctly.

When React has rendered this to the DOM it looks like the following:

[image]

I'm surprised by the fact there are multiple strings in there. Is this normal as I've not seen this behaviour before?

Comment: I guess it does. See how the jsx transpiled to javascript: https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwCwjAfAEgpgNnA9gAgN4DsCGBbGyA--yARAHTnEC-AhMAPTgRA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=

Comment: Probably the endpoint gives content in such format, name.join(" ") could help.